# Ini file read and write + add new property + matlab

Tags: matlab

How to read and write ini files: I want to add new property to an existing one. I want to write the ini file to temp file and finally add the new property to it. the new property will have head,name,desc, value and layout (like: line 1 & 3)

#--------------- 
 # head 
 # --------------
 [name]% type 
 # desc 
 value

```
fileData = [];
fh = fopen( fileName, 'r' ); % read handle
tname=tempname();
wfh =fopen(tname,'w'); % write handle
line = fgetl(fh);
val = '';
Prop ='';
type = '';
header = '';
desc= '';

while ischar(line)

    if strcmpi(line(1),'#') && strcmpi(line(3),'=')
        layout = line(2:end);
    elseif strcmpi(line(1),'#')&& ~strcmpi(line(3),'=')
        header = line(2:end);
    else 
        Prop = regexp(line,{'\[*\w+\]\s*%\s*.*\s*'},'match');
    [property data_type] = strtok(Prop,'%')
    prop_p = property{1};% property_name
    prop_per  = regexprep(prop_p,{'\[','\]'},'');
    prop = prop_per{1};
    Dtype = data_type{1}; % datatype
    dtype = strtrim(strrep(Dtype,'%',''));
    DATA_type = dtype{1};

end 



 % How can i define filedname (prop) for the 'layout' and 'header' as they are found in lines before the actual'prop'.

  % From command window

  % Undefined variable prop.

  % Error in ecco2511>add (line 212)
  % fileData.(prop{1}).layout = layout;


    desc = fgetl(fh); % description
    desc = desc(1:end);
    line = fgetl(fh);
    val = line(1:end);

    fileData.(prop).layout = layout;
    fileData.(prop).header = header;
    fileData.(prop).type = DATA_type;
    fileData.(prop).desc = desc;
    fileData.(prop).val = val;

    line = fgetl(fh); % keep reading

end

if ~isfield( fileData, propName)
    fileData.(propName).val = newVal;
    fileData.(propName).type = datatype;
    fileData.(propName).desc = description;
    fileData.(propName).layout = layout;
    fileData.(propName).header = header;

else
    error ( 'property %s already exists, use set to change its value',propName );
end

fileData = orderfields( fileData );
propNames = fieldnames( fileData );

for ii = 1:numel( propNames )

    fprintf(wfh,'%s\r',fileData.(propNames{ii}).layout);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
    fprintf(wfh,'%s\r',fileData.(propNames{ii}).header);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
    fprintf(wfh,'%s\r',fileData.(propNames{ii}).layout);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
    fprintf( wfh, '[%s]%s\r', (propNames{ii}),fileData.(propNames{ii}).type);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
    fprintf( wfh,'#%s\r',fileData.(propNames{ii}).desc);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
    fprintf( wfh,'%s\r',fileData.(propNames{ii}).val);
    fprintf(wfh,'\n');
end
fclose(fh);
fclose(wfh);
[status,errmsg]= movefile(tname,fileName,'f');
```

Comment: fprintf( wfh, '[%s]%%%s\r', propNames{ii},fileData.(propNames{ii}).type);

One of the parameters you are passing through %s is not a string, just add 

whos 'variable name' for both variables

before your fprintf line and then a breakpoint or "keyboard" after that and post what does it say. Someone may help.

Comment: Hi Sridutt, that is right the propName & type variable are cells. I would appreciate any help on this.                                  Name           Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

propNames      2x1               244  cell

Comment: Try cell_variable_name{index_number} to extract the cell contents as strings.

Comment: Hallo Sridutt , could you check my updated code. thanks

Comment: Shai , Thanks . However why i'm getting cell type while i use : 'string = cell_variable_name{index_number}' to extract string content of the cell . That is the reason i am getting the error.

Comment: You may get issues because one of your variables is called ``type`` - which is also a [Matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html?searchHighlight=type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [INI Config](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24992-ini-config) from MATLAB File Exchange.  It will allow you to read, write, and modify INI style files.  I have used it a number of times and it works quite well.